# Google Sheet ImportXml converts value of numbers wrong

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get coordinates from `geonames` api by `importXml` google sheet function. When I try this formula: `IMPORTXML(G2;"//lat")` where G2 is [the api](http://api.geonames.org/get?geonameId=2661852&username=).

I get 4.747.104,00 but the actual value would be 47.47104. As the values are different I can not only solve that by *10 or similar.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it was a mystery to me why the Germal locale reads the number `47.47104` as `4.747.104`. But you can get over this problem by using one custom function instead of three `ImportXml` functions

```
function parseXml(url) {
  let xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(),
      document = XmlService.parse(xml),
      root = document.getRootElement();
  return [[root.getChild('name').getText(),root.getChild('lat').getText(),root.getChild('lng').getText()]]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this does not work for me, when I try this I get 4,471.04 and in some cases (especially with the lng values) for example 753,599.

Comment: I'm sorry that my answer couldn't help you - but when I wrote down your formula, it immediately printed the correct value `47.47104`. I attached a link to the example table  [Stackoverflow ImportXML](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QK01RojWZJ-Tan2cGiwRf3se1DEuhbaHia0KAIxNe4w/edit?usp=sharing) Maybe you can also make an example of your table (leave only the calculation that gives you the wrong value) and share it - then it will be much easier to understand what caused the error

Comment: Thank you for your help! In your google sheet it also works with my formula – i made an example. But in my google sheet and also in others and new ones it doesn`t work. I haven't been working with these things for a long time and have no idea what the problem could be. But from the way it looks, it's probably not the formula. Are there any settings I need to change?

Comment: could you make a new Sheets in which such an error with a formula appears and share it - then it will be easier to understand what the problem is

Comment: I could not find the cause of your problem, but I can suggest a solution (you can see it in my answer)